# Why does a return statement break the conditional operator?

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

Experimenting with the conditional operator in ruby,

```
def nada
  false ? true : nil
end

def err
  false ? true : raise('false')
end
```

work as expected but

```
def reflection
  false ? true : return false
end
```

produces a `syntax error, unexpected keyword_false, expecting keyword_end`

```
def reflection
  false ? true : return(false)
end
```

and attempted with brackets `syntax error, unexpected tLPAREN, expecting keyword_end`

yet

```
def reflection
  false ? true : (return false)
end
```

works as expected, and the more verbose `if`...`then`...`else`...`end`

```
def falsy
  if false then true else return false end
end
```

also works as expected.

#### So what's up with the conditional (ternary) operator?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use it like this, by putting the entire `return` expression in parentheses:

```
def reflection
  false ? true : (return false)
end
```

Of course, it does not make much sense used like this, but since you're experimenting (good!), the above works! The error is because of the way the Ruby grammar works I suppose - it expects a certain structure to form a valid expression.

**UPDATE**

Quoting some information from a [draft specification](http://www.ipa.go.jp/osc/english/ruby/ruby_draft_specification_agreement.html):

> An expression is a program construct which make up a statement (see 12
>   ). A single expression can be a statement as an expression-statement
>   (see 12.2).12
>
> NOTE A diﬀerence between an expression and a statement is that an
>   expression is ordinarily used where its value is required, but a
>   statement is ordinarily used where its value is not necessarily
>   required. However, there are some exceptions. For example, a
>   jump-expression (see 11.5.2.4) does not have a value, and the value
>   of the last statement of a compound-statement can be used.

NB. In the above, *jump-expression* includes `return` among others.

Comment: odd that this works. I do wonder where the grammar for this is defined. Snippet added to question.

Comment: So is `(return false)` interpreted as an expression by ruby?

Comment: In Ruby almost everything behaves like an expression. For example, even when you define a `class`, the last "item" (expression) in that `class` definition is the value of the `class` (e.g. `puts class Hello;  @a = 5;end` will return `5`). `return` is a keyword and considered a statement, but ruby blurs that distinction in many cases. With the ternary operator, using `return` in parentheses probably satisfies ruby's grammar for the ternary operator, since `return` is also considered an expression.

Comment: You may find something useful in [this document](http://www.ipa.go.jp/osc/english/ruby/ruby_draft_specification_agreement.html).

Comment: `sleep` is the same in this context, e.g. in: `n.times { (foo = var_may_not_be_true_yet) ? (return foo) : (sleep 0.1) }`

Answer (score 6):

I think this is all related to the ruby parser.

- ruby parses `return` as the else-expression of the ternary operator
- ruby is then surprised when it finds `false` instead of `end`
- wrapping `return false` in parentheses causes ruby to interpret the entire thing as the else-expression
- `return(false)` doesn't work because ruby is still trying to interpret just the `return` part as the else-expression, and is surprised when it finds a left-parenthesis **(updated)**

---

Note:  I don't think this is a great answer.

A great answer could, for example, explain the parse errors with reference to the ruby grammar.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works if you surround `return false` in parentheses. Also: `if ... then ... else ... end` is an expression in ruby as well.

Comment: @sepp2k -- yes, I'm wondering if `(return false)` is an expression in ruby. ???   As to `if ... then ... else ... end`, I didn't say that it's not an expression -- I just said that it allows statements inside of it.

Comment: my rudimentary understanding of the design philosophy behind the language is that everything is an expression. `()` => nil which allows for `() || 1` => 1

Comment: @AlexanderWenzowski -- you may be right.  I've updated my answer to show my uncertainty.

Comment: re: return is not a function, true but `def nope; return(false); end; nope` still evaluates to `false`

Comment: @AlexanderWenzowski -- apologies for possibly wasting your time by starting off on a completely wrong track.

Answer (score 2):

The ternery operator is just that, an operator. You don't return from it. You return from functions. When you put a return in an if, you return from the function that the if is in. Since there is no variable awaiting assignment from the result of the if, there is no problem. When you return from the ternery operator, there is no value assigned to the variable.

Comment: Parsing your answer, I'm returning from the function whether the return statement is inside brackets or not. The ability to invoke the return statement at any point within a method is one of ruby's goodies. But I lose you at "no value assigned to the variable". Isn't "everything an object"? Do you mean that the conditional operator is an operator alone, and not an object descended from [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html)?

Comment: Yes, I misspoke. You do not have an x = in front of your operator. I should have said the expression has no value (to which you could assign to a variable but are not.) Thank you for keeping me honest.

Comment: cool. Thanks for taking the time both to answer and to reply!